# Sass-lint, ignore nesting

Tags: sass-lint

How to ignore this error:
`Class should be nested within its parent Class  force-element-nesting`.
I don't knwo how to ingore this error when I'm overriding soem classes with a lot of nesting in one line like:

```
// sass-lint:disable ???

.one.two.three.four .soemthing .else,
.one.three.hello .another. else 
{
    //
}
```

Currently I'm using `// sass-lint:disable-all` for all blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work with this:

```
// sass-lint:disable force-element-nesting

.one.two.three.four .soemthing .else,
.one.three.hello .another. else 
{
    //
}

// sass-lint:enable force-element-nesting
```

Enabling again to restore the rule.